# Langage to declare a circuit board

Tags: pcb-design

I am looking for a language that can declare a circuit board, and then draw it in schematic form or whatever. Can you tell me if such a thing even exists?

The common "language" people use to design circuit boards is some graphical tool like Eagle, KiCad, Altium or any of the plethora EDA packages https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_EDA_software. I am looking to create a text file instead, that will be processed and generate as output one of the EDA file formats.

*Detailed explanation:*

For example in the world of computer cloud infrastructure, there are several declarative languages that are used to define resources and create them. HashiCorp Terraform, AWS CloudFormation, OpenStack HOT, Azure ARM Templates, and more.

For example, if I need to create a circuit that has a battery, IR receiver, IR transmitted and an Arduino. Using this language I would just define which pin of each device needs to be connected to which other pin - and the output of the language can be a graphical representation of the circuit. As-if I designed it in KiCad or some other EDA.

One example for automatic dependency resolving is Graphviz. For example using Graphviz I can create a text file where each component is listed, along with all the dependencies and it creates a graphical representation from this in some graphics format (svg, png, ...).

Example Graphviz dot notation file
https://gist.github.com/kesor/2b858d218a25d22f27eefb780c6b1a17

When rendered it looks like this
https://i.stack.imgur.com/k67qz.jpg

Comment: What about Gerber?

Comment: Gerber is used to describe directions, go there, go here, etc... It can be the output format of such a language. But I mean something of a bit higher level. Just write down the component types and pin numbers, and it generates a gerber (or whatever) as the output.

Comment: @winny I think he wants a software that would draw a neat shematic from some textual representation of the netlist. Well, I think it is really (I mean, **really**) optimistic.

Comment: @dim Not so sure, I think he wants to give a list of component connections and get a board layout automatically. It's actually a nice enough idea, I think the problem is the amount of human judgement actually involved in design. Like, you do one design then, "oooh, if i move that and that and that there, my connections to something else are shorter and the fixings are better placed, and..."

Comment: The complexity of board design essentially *requires* WYSIWYG interactivity. "Batch" EDA would really only work for fairly trivial designs.

Comment: @Evgeny What form of language could be used to portay a jpeg image? If you can think of none or think my question is stupid, please reflect on it.

Comment: @ianBland Graphviz already does this today, but it would require quite a lot of work to add a notion of a component to it and make it a bit simpler to use. Graphviz is basically an algorithm embedded in a language to describe graphs, very powerful.

Comment: Then you probably have your answer.

Comment: @Andyaka here is an example -

language - https://gist.github.com/kesor/2b858d218a25d22f27eefb780c6b1a17

rendered - http://imgur.com/a/kiUR2

Comment: I think some of the EDA vendors have had a go at this, but the trouble is it can cope with the easy cases but not the hard ones, at which point people need to go back to the traditional tools. A good read of the websites of Cadence etc might turn up something.

Comment: (search term "Verilog to PCB") - the generic term is "HDL"

Comment: @pjc50 I did stumble on that, but it looks extremely complex and in general suitable for not just describing the circuit but also its operation in time.

Comment: Supporting @pjc50. However the only case I've heard where this is actually used is that Apple(?) at one point did PCB design with Verilog.

Comment: @dim It was a partial joke on my behalf. But it's not unrelated to verilog and VHDL which are both languages to describe a circuit.

Comment: @Evgeny well, generally you end up wanting to add annotations which specify behaviour so the tools can cope with it. Automatic layout is no good if it doesn't keep differential pairs together or puts decoupling capacitors miles away from the respective components.

Comment: (your stated example sounds like a job for Fritzing, but it's also a really simple one; better to think of a variety of use cases)

Answer (score 6):

There are a bunch (dozens) of common formats for netlists.

Netlists describe the logical connections between component pins, and are logically equivalent to a schematic (minus any notes and other information such as rules that is communicated in the schematic- many of which are actually required to create an optimal PCB from the schematic).

Drawing a good human-readable schematic is an art form. As far as I know nobody has put in the effort it would take into trying to create excellent schematics automatically. I don't see that it would be impossible - there are a number of general rules, and machine learning could suck up all the many examples (assuming it knew which ones were atrocious) and learn from them.

It's possible to create a PCB without a schematic- the schematic is just for humans to understand, but the netlist does not necessarily contain information on how to handle power connections, differential pairs, controlled impedance conductors, guard rings, shields, parts that need to be close  and so on. If you've ever seen a PCB laid out by a dolt that doesn't understand electrics you will understand- 150mm (6") conductors run to a clock crystal etc. When you start laying out a PCB you usually see the parts (which have to be 'placed' ) and a rat's next of connections that represents the netlist graphically.

Generally auto-placement and schematics (I've seen a few examples of machine generated schematics) are the hardest for automation. Autorouting is useful in some cases, though humans still tend to do better, so far, with machine assistance that enforces pre-determined rules such as clearances by net, trace width by net, etc.

Answer (score 2):

I started working on something along these lines for doing projects with lots of LEDs in grids - allow sensible diff for version control, allowing inclusion of modules and macros for generating multiples and repetitions. This wasn't based on net list, but on specifying tracks directly from pin to pin similar to logo. I had it rendering when you changed the text, but for anything non-trivial, you would need to have two way interaction between the rendering and the text, which becomes a lot more work than the tool will save me, and I didn't want to start yet-another open source EDI editor project.

Comment: Knew a guy who did something like this, also for LEDs. IIRC it was for arrays that were regularly placed in polar coordinates. A pretty simple and specialized application, but a pain to do in EDA packags at that time.